# how to call method in button onclick event in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a MVC application.

In Edit View, I want to have save/submit button and cancel button.

By default MVC given 'back to list' link.this link calls index() method.

Now, I want to call this index() method on Cancel button's Onclick event , how to do this ?

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return validate();" id="btnSubmit" />  
<input type="Button" value ="Cancel" onclick="Index()"style=" font-size:"1.2em"/>
```

What changes I have to make in above code?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `window.location.href` to redirect to a specified url:

```
<input type="Button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")'" style=" font-size:"1.2em"/>
```

or simply use an anchor instead of a button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
```

Comment: How to call a method by button without redirecting to any view? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557278/invoking-a-controllers-action-by-button-in-view-without-redirecting-to-any-view?noredirect=1#comment39909550_25557278