# Invoking a controller's action by button in View without redirecting to any view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I wanted to add a button to my ASP .NET MVC WebApplication's view which will invoke a method:

```
 public void  UpdateDatabase(int personId, int surveyId) {
          //updating,modifying database
        }
```

but besides that nothing at all will happen so user will not see any visible changes. The user will not be redirected, visible content of the site will not change, page will not be reloaded.

Just like you click a button with no listener associated with it.

I have tried

```
 <p> @Html.ActionLink("Update database", "UpdateDatabase", new { personId = Model.Item1.Id, surveyId = survey.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

but I am redirected to site:

```
http://localhost:17697/Person/SubmitSurvey?personId=6&surveyId=6
```

which is empty.

I would like to achieve only invoking `UpdateDatabase` method.

**EDIT:**

[image]

EDIT2:

The view looks like this:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
@*<p>
        Number of Surveys: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
    </p>*@

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <p> @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SubmitSurvey", new { personId = Model.Item1.Id, surveyId = survey.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
        <button id='mybutton'>Click Me</button>
        <script>
            $('#mybutton').click(function(){
                $.post("Person/SubmitSurvey", { personId: {@Model.Item1.Id }, surveyId: {@survey.Id } }, function (data) {
                    alert('updated');
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

and the controllers action:

PersonController:

```
 public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, int surveyId) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TEXT");
        }
```

and the result after clicking the button:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

My `RouteConfig`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication2 {
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

### }

### EDIT 4

I tried also this:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
@*<p>
        Number of Surveys: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
    </p>*@

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <p> @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SubmitSurvey", new { personId = Model.Item1.Id, surveyId = survey.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
        <script>
            function BtnOnclick1() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Person/SubmitSurvey")',
                    data: {
                        personId: '@Model.Item1.Id',
                        surveyId: '@survey.Id'
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="javascript:BtnOnclick1();" />

    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

but I get runtime exception: `There is no definition of „BtnOnclick1”.

> Unhandled exception at line 47, column 12 in script block
>
> 0x800a1391 - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: Brak definicji „BtnOnclick1”

Comment: Have your tried to search for something like "call method from browser in ASP.Net"? There should be couple answer how to use ajax for that...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I am still searching for it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have found sth like this: `@{
   new FooClass().Foo(...);}` but I need a button which invokes it (like in OP).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Could you please take a look at edit 2 it almost works but the wrong method is invoked `_Survey1`(the name of razor view I posted) instead of `SumbitSurvey`.

Comment: "Syntax errors" are likely due to confused VS editor... Note that code in text form is different than image (have extra `{}`). Code overall looks reasonable, I'd recommend looking at resulting HTML/JavaScript to see if it makes sense. Possibly JS is different from what you think will be generated and you sending `null` for ID.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Could you for the last time :(, look at the edit 4?

Comment: Looks ok to me... Make sure to carefully look at browser's debug console for any errors/warnings. Likely something wrong with you script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery's $.get (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or $.post (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). After including reference to jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
<button id='mybutton'>Click Me</button>

<script>
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $.post( "mysite/UpdateDatabase", {personId: "@Model.Item1.Id", surveyId: "@survey.Id"}, function( data ) {
        alert('updated');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'll try it right now I don't know JQuery enought. Can it be done by any HTML helper methods or simpler?

Comment: Nothing out of the box in MVC I'm aware of. But there is no need when you have jQuery. Just include a reference like `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you, there is only one problem I posted in the EDIT of the OP, there is something wrong with the syntax and I don't see anything wrong. Thankfuly reference to jQuery was added when I created t It doesn't say what is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Could you please take a look at EDIT2, the wrong method is invoked and causes error.

Comment: Can you check your `App_Data\RouteConfig.cs` file for route configuration? Also check the URL in the `$.post` method: might need a `/` prefix like `/person/submitsurvey`.

Comment: I added `/` and posted RouteConfig.cs in EDIT3.

Comment: Ok so the reason of the error is that your script (**EDIT2**) is never run. Clicking the button does not invoke your script.

Comment: are you sure you added reference to jQuery? also - i was missing double quotes in the $.post code - now updated in my post. try firebug addon in firefox and see what's happening when you click the button.