# How do I create a button's onclick in code behind in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I want to have a onclick event in the my code behind in the controller class of my code but how do I do this with mvc. I can't find anything on google all I've found is for button type submit but I don't want a button of type submit.

This is my button in my view:

```
<button type="button" id="game" onclick="">
</button>
```

Comment: You would use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Here is an answer for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15338552/2777098

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an ASP.NET web forms Server side events behavior, you will have to create it yourself.
You CAN do (easily) an Ajax call to a controller, get a response and do what ever you want with it. More information [Here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html).

Small example of attaching client side (javascript) onclick event to your button, that calls a controller action on the server and show the results in the console. you need to change this line

> @Html.ActionLink("*Controller*", "*Action*")

with your controller and action names.

```
 <script type="text/jscript">
    $('#game').click(function () {
        var url = '@Html.ActionLink("*Controller*", "*Action*")';
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
           console.log(data);           
           /// Add javascript code here to execute when you get the answer from the controller  
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onclick is a javascript event. You can't react from your mvc controller to it directly. If you need to react to anything that happens on the client, you have to do a postback, either by using a form or using ajax and doing asynchronous request...